# VueJS/Quasar cordova android gera app em branco

Tags: apache-cordova, vue.js, quasar

Olá,

Comecei a usar o Quasar Framework afim de criar um app hibrido para Android.

Após seguir os passos de instalação (WINDOWS 10), criei um projeto padrão, ou seja, ainda não desenvolvi nada, executei o comando para rodar o app no emulador:
$ quasar dev -m cordova -T android

o processo não apresentou nenhum erro, o app foi instalado com sucesso no emulador, porem quando eu abro o app no emulador apresenta uma tela em branco.

alguem consegue me ajudar com isso?

Desde de já muito obrigado!

Comment: Já tive esse problema com angular, ou seja, a tela branca se da pq no apk gerado não é possível fazer requisições internas, solucionei emulando um mini servidor com ngrok e linkei todas as requisições novamente, passou a funcionar tanto em mobile quanto em desktop

Comment: vc poderia por gentileza me dar mais orientações de como fazer isso? pra eu tentar? pelo que eu entendi então o problema não é do quasar nem do cordova, é isso?

Comment: vou montar uma resposta

Comment: Vlw Felipe, muito obrigado

Comment: Usando o ngrok como fica quando eu for distribuir? Ele já vai junto com o APK?

Comment: Perdão, não tive tempo de concluir ontem, mas já respondi

Answer (score 0):

Em ambiente de desenvolvimento cada requisição é feita localmente, a não ser que você linke tudo externamente, por exemplo em...

```
<script src="/lib/ionic/js/ionic.bundle.js"></script>
```

Você pega a lib localmente como se fosse `localhost:8000/lib/ionic/js/ionic.bundle.js`

Em desktop esse endereço faz sentido, pois você está emulando um servidor interno, mas e em outro dispositivo? ele não saberá oque é esse localhost:8000

Aí entra o [ngrok](https://ngrok.com/), basta criar um servidor na porta 8000 com o comando `ngrok http 8000`, ele irá gerar 2 url´s com acesso ao seu servidor uma com certificado e a outra sem.

aí basta linkar corretamente as suas chamadas, exemplo...

```
<script src="http://81ade093.ngrok.io/lib/ionic/js/ionic.bundle.js"></script>
```